# Proving iff statement concerning transitivity

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

I am asked to show that $A$ is transitive $iff$ $A\subset\ P(A)$. My definition is that a set A is transitive if whenever $x\in\ a\in\ A$, then $x\in A$.

My attempt at a proof:

I started with let $x\in\ a\in\ A$. By the Power Set Axiom, it follows that for the set $A$, there exists a set $P(A)$ such that for all $a$, $a\in\ P(A)$ $iff$ $a\subset\ A$. I am not too sure if this is the correct way to approach this side of the proof.

For the other direction, I have let $A\subset\ P(A)$, then if $a\in\ A$ it follows that $a\in\ P(A)$. Then, I am not too sure how to continue to get to the fact of being transitive. I think I should also be using the Power set axiom here as well but I am not sure.

For reference, the Power Set Axiom reads: For any set A, there exists a set B such that for all x, $x\in\ b$ $iff$ $x\subset\ A$. Our B is what we call the Power set.

Comment: "$x\in\ a\in\ A$".  I realize how tempting it is, but don't ever, ever, ever write that.  Write $x \in a$ and $a \in A$.  ""$x\in\ a\in\ A$" is syntactically meaningless and unparseable.  And as you are trying to prove transitivity it is *excedingly* misleading.

Comment: @fleablood Okay, this is just the word for word definition of transitivity our set theory professor provided us. Although, I do agree it does not seem well written.

Comment: Oh.... you are forgiven then.  But .... sheesh.

Comment: @fleablood Trust me, most of the definitions I am given make me do a double take.

Comment: The definition "$x \in a \land a \in A \implies x \in A$" is fine but the syntax is the equivalent of a run-on-sentence.  It's the equivalent of saying "The man ate a sandwich had mayonaise".  Yes, we can probably work it out but math is supposed to be precise and about figuring at what logically is necessary; not what is similar and convenient.  And if our conclusions and processes are supposed to be precise, I feel it's "bad faith" to be casual and sloppy in our syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I'd say you're "using the power set axiom" which establishes the existence of a power set for every set. I guess you use it to prove the question isn't referring to a nonexistent object, but otherwise you're just using the *definition* of a power set.

I'm not sure I follow your reasoning for the first direction. You are trying to show $A\subset P(A).$ The standard way to establish that is to take an arbitrary $a\in A$ and show that $a$ must also be an element of $P(A).$ So let $a\in A.$ By the definition of the power set, $a\in P(A)$ if and only if $a\subset A,$ so we need to show $a\subset A.$ Again, the way we will show this is to take an arbitrary $x\in a$ and show that $x\in A.$ So let $x\in a.$ We have $x\in a$ and $a\in A$ so by the definition of transitivity $x\in A.$ Thus we have shown $a\subset A$ and thus $a\in P(A).$ Since we started with $a\in A$ and showed this implies $a\in P(A),$ we have established that $A\subset P(A).$

For the other way, to show transitivity, you need to show that if $x\in a$ and $a\in A$ then it follows that $x\in A.$ So assume $x\in a$ and $a\in A$ and set out to prove $x\in A.$ We use the assumption that $A\subset P(A)$ which as you indicated implies $a\in P(A)$ which in turn by definition of power set implies $a\subset A.$ Since we have $x\in a,$ by the definition of "$a\subset A$", we have $x\in A.$ And we're done.

Comment: I see, for some reason the definition I was given for the power set is called the Power set Axiom.

Comment: Then, would there be a way to just do a chain or equivalent statements instead?

Comment: I believe you said even in your question that the power set axiom is: "For any set A, there exists a set B such that for all x, $x\in\ b$ $iff$ $x\subset\ A$. Our B is what we call the Power set. " This is a statement of existence with the definition of what exists embedded in it. (and I don't know what you mean by your second question).

Comment: I mean can we do a list of iff statements in this case?

Comment: Oh you mean rather than doing one way then the other. Sure: $A\subset P(A)$ iff $\forall a \in A,\; a\in P(A)$ iff $\forall a\in A,\; a\subset A$ iff $\forall a\in A, \; \forall x\in a, x\in A$

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant, but could we start by saying $A$ is transitive $iff$ for $x\in\ a\in\ A$ then $x\in A$ iff .....

Comment: Or is starting with the power set then ending at transitivity also okay? I just have not had to do the opposite direction before to show iff statements.

Comment: Yeah, my rightmost statement is equivalent to transitivity so just run it backwards.

Comment: An equivalence is symmetric by nature.

Comment: I think what I mean is do I start by saying let  A be a set and x,a be arbitrary and then going into the definitions?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66043/discussion-between-spaceisdarkgreen-and-sam).